# how to fix OpenShift maven project build error

Tags: java, maven, build, openshift

I tried to build a maven project with JBoss Web Server 3.1 Apache Tomcat 8+MySQL(with https) in OpenShift.

However error occurs like this.

```
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException 
Aborting due to error code 1 from Maven build
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat8-openshift@sha256:29470583ce1511dbbe8e2552b7f0278d0d74595c42a00632cd23fda1ffab361e
```

The maven project built successfully in eclipse.

But OpenShift continuously has an error.

I entered the URL(http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException) in the error log. It says the error is related to plugin. But I can't figure out what kind of plugin and what it is.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more context? How does your full pom.xml look like? What plugins are you using and what maven target are you executing?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out. It was the pom.xml configuration problem. I changed the configuration like a sample in youtube 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QM4A-swC2Y'.